# wrong encode when update pdf meta data using ghostscript and pdfmark

Tags: pdf, encoding, ghostscript, pdf-manipulation

I have a base pdf file, and want to update the title into Chinese (UTF-8) using ghostscript and pdfmark, command like below

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=result.pdf base.pdf pdfmarks
```

And the pdfmarks file (encoding is **UTF-8 without BOM**) is below

```
[ /Title (敏捷开发)
/Author (Larry Cai)
/Producer (xdvipdfmx (0.7.8))
/DOCINFO pdfmark
```

The command is successfully executed, while when I check the properties of the `result.pdf`

The title is changed to `æŁ‘æ“·å¼•å‘`

Please give me hints how to solve this, are there any parameters in `gs` command or pdfmark?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PDF Reference states that the Title entry in the document info dictionary is of type 'text string'. Text strings are defined as using either PDFDocEncoding *or* UTF-16BE with a Byte Order Mark (see page 158 of the 1.7 PDF Reference Manual).

So you cannot specify a Title using UTF-8 without a BOM.

I would imagine that if you replace the Title string with a string defining the content using UTF-16BE with a BOM then it will work properly. I would suggest you use a hex string rather than a regular PostScript string to specify the data, simply for ease of use.

Comment: Thanks, and with the tool from http://blog.tremily.us/posts/PDF_bookmarks_with_Ghostscript/, I managed to get it work. 
And the tool will convert it to "UTF-16BE with a Byte Order Mark"

Answer (score 2):

Using the idea from Happyman Chiu my solution is next. Get a UTF-16BE string with BOM by

```
echo -n '(敏捷开发)' | iconv -t utf-16 |od -x -A none | tr -d ' \n' | sed 's/./\U&/g;s/^/</;s/$/>/'
```

You will get `<FEFF0028654F63775F0053D10029>`. Substitute this for title.

```
/Title <FEFF0028654F63775F0053D10029>
```

Answer (score 0):

follow [pdfmark for docinfo metadata in pdf is not accepting accented characters in Keywords or Subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010015/pdfmark-for-docinfo-metadata-in-pdf-is-not-accepting-accented-characters-in-keyw)

I use this function to create the string from utf-8 for info.txt, to be used by gs command.

```
  function str_in_pdf($str){
    $cmd = sprintf("echo '%s'| iconv -t utf-16 |od -x -A none",$str);
    exec($cmd,$out,$ret);
    return "<" . implode("",$out) .">";
  }
```