# Why does cairo_ps exported R plots do show text in Word just as symbols?

Tags: r, ms-word, rgraph

I need to import high quality R plots into Microsoft Word which later needs to be transformed into a pdf (thesis). At first I tried high resolution PNGs, but the printout was really blurry.

```
png(height=2500, width=2750, filename="correlations3.png", units="px",type="cairo-png",antialias="default",pointsize=5,res=500)
```

As I read somewhere that postscript is the way to go, I tried `postscript()`, but the font is displaying really jagged in word.

```
postscript("Correlations4.eps",height=10, width=12,pointsize=8,paper="special",family = "Arial", onefile = FALSE,horizontal = FALSE,colormodel = "rgb")
```

I tried different font types, but it didn’t help. I tried to embed the fonts, but it did not improve the quality of the text either.

`Cairo_ps` seems to produce a nice plot, but unfortunately the text is just showing as symbols in word and I have no idea why??

```
cairo_ps(height=5, width=7, filename="Correlations11.eps",family="Times New Roman",antialias="default",pointsize=5)
```

I’m a bit at a loss here and any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: check the places you read again. I also heard postscript was somehow good, but later had that advice refuted pretty handily in favor of only creating PDF plots (e.g., [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619079/postscript-versus-pdf-as-an-output-format), [2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217511/why-do-people-still-use-postscript), [3](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60778/fundamental-differences-pstricks-tikz-pgf-and-others)). And you should look into LaTeX as an alternative to your current workflow.

Comment: Yes, I plan to use Latex in the future, but at the moment I'm a bit under time constraints (have to submit my thesis pretty soon) so I have to stick to Word for the moment. I tried to import my plots as pdfs (which looked very sharp originally), but as soon as I import them into Word they are just plain unsharp....

Comment: I'm surprised that you can even get decent result with non-microsoft vector format (e.g. eps) on Word. Have you tried exporting as tif instead? Make sure the output size does not get scaled when placed into word drawing palette.