# Reporting With Unicode

Tags: asp.net, reporting

Firs of all I apologize for my English.

I am developing an asp.net application withe .NET Frame work 3.5 and Sql Server 2008. I am using RDLC for reporting. I have to generate reports in 'Hindi , so I have to use Unicode.

**While Running the application and  getting report in browser:**

in aspx page it shows all Unicode characters properly, no matter what font I have set for it.If font is 'Times New Roman' or 'Arial Unicode MS'  the output is same and proper(in the browser). But exporting it to PDF it depends on what font I have set for it. When I have set Font Times New Roman it shows some thing like  ???????? instead of Unicode Characters and when I set Font to Arial Unicode MS it works but still there is some problem with few characters.

1. As we have many fonts pre-installed in our windows systems (like Arial, Times New Roman  etc.) , Is there any separate set of Fonts specially for Unicode?
2. If There is a separate set of fonts for Unicode  then what Font are pre-installed on system?(Which font I should use in my web application that it should appear properly on all system, users must not need to install any kind of fonts to see the report on their machine).
3. If There is not a separate set of fonts for Unicode (as it shows all Unicode characters in aspx page properly no matter what font I choose ) then what is problem with exporting reports to the pdf?

**And finally  It may be  I have some misconcept/miscode about uincode and reporting, then  What should I do to generate reports that can be  converted in pdf with Unicode ?( I need reports in both formate aspx and pdf). or I should use some other tools for reporting.**

Answer (score 0):

because in client side you must have to install that hindi font..

Answer (score 0):

According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/163029/1828416, most likely, you need to embbed the font or the characters in your PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Arial Unicode MS Bold** for all purposes. It works for me. Arial Unicode Normal gives some problem.