# How can I render symbols that will be shown in HTML and PDF?

Tags: c#, html, pdf

We are generating files that render to HTML and PDF and I'm using wingdong font but lately we noticed that wingding symbols are not shown on android devices browsers.
Does someone have a solution for this?

btw base code is written in C# with iText.

Comment: From a bit of research, it appears that Wingdings is a special font you have to install.  Not natively supported.  I would look at either using Unicode symbols, or images itself.   This link may help you replace your Wingdings with Unicode:  http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings.html

Comment: I tried to do that but how can I implement unicode into pdf file? (even just for testing) and I was wondering if there is any other font rather then winding that is more globally though the QA found that wingding is only missing in android devices browsers...

Comment: I'm just going by some google searching here.  I've not generated PDF files in a long time (outside of simple reporting tools that magically handle the PDF creation).  Unicode in PDF:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128162/unicode-in-pdf

Comment: The font needs to be installed on the target device unless you embed the font in the PDF

Comment: @DavidG the font is visible in the pdf but not on android browsers. so the problem is android doesn't support wingding even if its embeded to pdf.

Comment: The **font** needs to be embedded in the PDF, not the text

Comment: @DavidG as I said it won't help cause HTML files won't show certain fonts.

Comment: @EricBurdo thanks for the links I'm looking into it.